# Compare two object as Array;

Tags: c#

How to compare two objects which may be is two Arrays.

```
  var arrayServer = serv as Array;
  var arrayLocal = local as Array;
```

I don't now why, but I can't use SequenceEqual for `arrayServer` or `arrayLocal` .

Comment: In what way do you want to compare them?

Comment: @Glorin Oakenfoot by elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't use `SequenceEqual` for `arrayServer` or `arrayLocal` .

That's because `Array` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` which is necessary for `SequenceEqual`.  Instead of casting to array  I would cast to an `IEnumerable<T>` (with `T` being the appropriate type of the collection items):

```
var arrayServer = serv as IEnumerable<{type}>;
var arrayLocal = local as IEnumerable<{type}>;
```

or use `Cast`:

```
var arrayServer = serv.Cast<{type}>();
var arrayLocal = local.Cast<{type}>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SequenceEqual` is one of LINQ methods, which are implemented as extensions on generic `IEnumerable<T>`. `Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but you can get generic `IEnumerable<T>` from it by calling either `OfType` or `Cast`:

```
bool areEqual = arrayLocal.Cast<theType>().SequenceEqual(arrayServer.Cast<theType>());
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the elements of 2 arrays you can use a loop:

```
bool itemsEqual = true;
int i = 0;
while(itemsEqual && i < arrayServ.Count)
{
    if(arrayServ[i].Equals(arrayLocal[i])
    {
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    itemsEqual = false;
    return itemsEqual;
}
return itemsEqual;
```

This will iterate through the serv array and compare the items to the items of local at the same index. If all of them are equal, nothing much will happen and true will be returned. If any comparison returns false, false will be returned. Though using arrays isn't exactly fun.